# Is there a way to get return values from python functions called by a builder in SCons?

Tags: python, scons

I'm using an SCons [builder to call a python function](http://scons.org/doc/2.0.1/HTML/scons-user/c3762.html), usually with a target specified as a file. However in some situations, it would be handy to return an object, but still keep the dependencies, e.g. to pass a variable to another builder.

Builder functions [*must*](http://scons.org/doc/1.2.0/HTML/scons-user/x3524.html) return 0 or None, but is there any other way to return some variables from a function called by a builder?

This dysfunctional script hopefully explains what I'd like to do:

```
import os
env = Environment(ENV = os.environ)

def give_me_5(foo):
    foo = 5
    return foo # This must be 0 or None...

bar = give_me_5(4)  
print 'How many? ', bar
#How many? 5

builder_bar = env.Command(
        source=None,
        target=None,
        action=give_me_5,
        foo = 4
        ) #Command doesn't return functions variables

print 'How many? ', builder_bar
#How many? []
```

But I want:  `How many? 5`

Comment: If you found a better solution than [mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43056103/3657941), would you mind posting it as an answer to this question?

Comment: I will, but no success so far. I've been trying some detours based on @bdbaddog answer.

Comment: Were you able to get help from the mailing list?

Answer (score 1):

Builders return an array of Node()s.
Value nodes are a type which could be the target.

That said your example won't work.

As the script is run, it builds the DAG, and then the DAG is walked and the actions are run.

So the action itself won't be run until after the SConscripts are run.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to pass `foo` between two `Command` builders by using a file:

```
import os
import json

JSON_FILE_NAME = 'give_me_5.json'

env = Environment(ENV=os.environ)

def give_me_5(target, source, env):
    d = env.Dictionary()
    print "foo = %s" % d['foo']
    for t in target:
        foo = 5
        with open(str(t), 'w') as json_file:
            json.dump(foo, json_file)
    return None

env.Command(source=None,
            target=JSON_FILE_NAME,
            action=give_me_5,
            foo=4)

def get_foo(target, source, env):
    for s in source:
        with open(str(s), 'r') as json_file:
            foo = json.load(json_file)
        os.unlink(str(s))
    print "How many? ", foo
    return None

env.Command(source=JSON_FILE_NAME,
            target=None,
            action=get_foo)
```

**Output**

```
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
give_me_5(["give_me_5.json"], [])
foo = 4
get_foo(["give_me_5"], ["give_me_5.json"])
How many?  5
scons: done building targets.
```

Note how the `source` and `target` are used to get the `Command` instances to run. Also notice that the `'give_me_5.json'` file is removed after being read in `get_foo` by the `os.unlink` call. This causes the file to be created every time. In addition, there is an example of how to get the `foo` value from the `env` parameter.

A SCons expert might be able to point out a better way to share data between `Builder` instances. I used JSON to serialize the data, but that limits the type of data that can be shared. I am really only providing this answer as a proof-of-concept in case you are really stuck and need a solution immediately.

Comment: Thanks, @David Cullen that is actually almost exactly how I've been doing it, saving dict to json or xml or sometimes values to short text files. I was hoping there was a more direct path to pass arguments, as the python function builder is rather neat.

Comment: @Tbb: You should probably send a message to the [SCons Users Mailing List](https://pairlist4.pair.net/mailman/listinfo/scons-users). The documentation specifically states, "...there's a lot that SCons can do that isn't yet covered in this User's Guide." The folks on the mailing list might know a better way to do this.

Comment: you are probably right. There are not many questions about SCons at SE.

Answer (score 0):

You can mutate a variable outside the function:

```
bar = [None]

def give_me_5(foo):
    foo = 5
    bar[0] = foo

...

print 'How many? ', bar[0]
```

More fully:

```
import os
env = Environment(ENV = os.environ)

builder_bar = [None]

def give_me_5(foo):
    foo = 5
    builder_bar[0] = foo

env.Command(
        source=None,
        target=None,
        action=give_me_5,
        foo = 4
        )

print 'How many? ', builder_bar[0]
# How many?  5
```

Comment: Thanks, but the question refers to dependencies in SCons. I've clarified it better.

Comment: @Tbb I don't see how that's relevant. You should still be able to do what I've shown.

Comment: SCons builds according to dependencies, Python is only the scripting language. I'm trying to find a way to tell SCons that the returned object is a needed target, probably by using a builder, env.Command() that defines source and target. Usually, files to build.

Comment: @Tbb I still don't see what your problem is. I've expanded my answer to explain the intended usage.

Comment: @AlexHall: Did you run this? I get this output `How many?  None`

Comment: @DavidCullen the first snippet is not meant to be run, I was just giving the structure. I don't know how to run the second snippet because I don't know what `Environment` or `Command` are. The point is to put the `print` at the end after `give_me_5` runs via the `Command`, whenever that happens (the way OP hoped to do `builder_bar = env.Command(...)` I assumed that it runs immediately).

Comment: @AlexHall: The problem with your code is that, as written, `give_me_5` will never run. SCons is a build system and the code in the SConstruct file does not run from top to bottom.

Comment: @DavidCullen ah, I see now. I had assumed I didn't need knowledge of SCons. Are there any limitations on the arguments, e.g. being picklable? If a single instance is passed to two `Commands`, will that same instance be shared as it appears, or will they be copied in the background? I'm wondering if `give_me_5` can be an object with a `__call__` method for the `action` but also behave as a target or whatever OP needs, using state that is updated by `__call__`.